# jQuery function to control what user types in a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My initial idea was something like that:

```
$(document).on("element","event", function(e){
});
```

But I have some doubts about this function:

1. which value I should use for "element"? I could use something like this: `'input[type=text]'` or I should use a class for the element (like `class="validate"`) and use `".validate"` for instance)
2. which value I should use for `"event"`? I could use `onfocus` from element input, or do jQuery have a particular nomenclature for this type of event?
3. for each key presses (which seems I should use `var key = which` to capture), how I could check if it's a number or a letter?
4. using the regex string, how I could get the type of the character in a specific position? for instance, with the regex: `[0-9]{2}/[A-Z]{2}/[0-9]{4}`, the position 2 should return 'number' as type, the position 3 should return letter, and the position 2 should return 'symbol'.

Anyone can give me some help here?

**UPDATE**

Let me try be more clear about my question:

I initially think about create this jquery function in my project:

```
$(document).on("element","event", function(e){
    //
});
```

But I have no idea how "event" I should listener here (I could use the same events available for the input atribute from html?) and like to know what name use for element (I ever use the ID or class from element, and jquery examples always use on of them, but how I could use the own element name, like input - I see once this being used: input[name=something], can I use this too: input[type=text]?).

In relation to the content of the function, I imagine this pseudo-code:

```
1- tam = size of string (calculated based on regex - already have a function to d this).
2- model[] = array of characteres with 'tam' elements (ok to me, too).
3- initialize counter=0.
4- for each key pressed by user:
4.1- type = store the type of the character in the position 'counter' of 'model[]' - I think I can use the regex to do this, but I don't know how.
4.2- if the character has same type from 'type' variable, store it in model[counter] and increment counter.
```

So, basicly, my question is find a way of, given a regex, find what type of character should be in each position (I explain that with example in the item 4 above).

Comment: There are too many questions here, and no code. Please try first, read the jQuery docs, when you get stuck come back with the code, explain what failed, and post a demo to reproduce your particular issue.

Comment: I am stuck right now with the first question: which values I should use for declare the function? And, despite all the questions, all what I want it's a way of be able to request something like that: regex[position] and receives as response the type of charactershould be in this position.

Comment: I just update my question to try be more clear about my question.

Comment: Did you have a look at input masking as I suggested. I have given a regex demo link also in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can restrict/validate what your users type in the input fields.

**Method 1**

You can use input masking, a great way to improve data validation in forms. Masking allows you to only accept data in a certain format, type. Have a look at this - https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

**Masking Demo** - http://robinherbots.github.io/jquery.inputmask/

This also accepts regex as you need, can be implemented using the library something like this -

```
<input id="example2" data-inputmask-regex="[a-za-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?" />
```

**REGEX WORKING DEMO** - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/Clzem

Note - This method actually restricts the user from typing or entering anything that does not comply to your given pattern in the mask.

**Method 2**

You can use different input types to control the input eg. text, email, password, number etc.

Ref - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Note - This method just defines the type of input control that will be rendered, whether password type or a number type. Helps browsers accept data in those formats.

Comment: Ok, I already using the different input types to control the input, and besides this, I using the atribute 'pattern'. I want now be able to check character by character if what is being typed matches with the pattern, and for this I want, basicly, request something like that: regex[position] and receive as response what type of character should be in this specific position.

Comment: @KleberMota - yes input masking will let you use regex to monitor character by character that the correct format is being typed. Please look at the documentation on github for the library I gave you.

Comment: @KleberMota - I have updated my answer with a regex demo - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/Clzem